# How to compare timestamp dates with date-only parameter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, datetime, date

In a SQL statement, how do I compare a date saved as TIMESTAMP with a date in YYYY-MM-DD format?

Ex.: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp = '2012-05-25'`

I want this query returns all rows having timestamp in the specified day, but it returns only rows having midnight timestamp.

thanks

Answer (score 189, accepted):

You can use the `DATE()` function to extract the date portion of the timestamp:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2012-05-25'
```

Though, if you have an index on the timestamp column, this would be faster because it could utilize an index on the timestamp column if you have one:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE timestamp BETWEEN '2012-05-25 00:00:00' AND '2012-05-25 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Through a small test I just ran, I found using BETWEEN to be faster by a factor of 10X  Just FYI

Comment: Use a date where it's clear what number means what type.

Answer (score 16):

As suggested by some, by using `DATE(timestamp)` you are applying manipulation to the column and therefore you cannot rely on the index ordering.

However, using `BETWEEN` would only be reliable if you include the milliseconds. In the example timestamp `BETWEEN '2012-05-05 00:00:00' AND '2012-05-05 23:59:59'` you exclude records with a timestamp between `2012-05-05 23:59:59.001` and `2012-05-05 23:59:59.999`. However, even this method has some problems, because of the datatypes precision. Occasionally 999 milliseconds is rounded up.

The best thing to do is:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE date>='2012-05-05' AND date<'2012-05-06'
```

Answer (score 13):

```
 WHERE cast(timestamp as date) = '2012-05-05'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp >= '2012-05-05 00:00:00' 
    AND timestamp <= '2012-05-05 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a conversion function of MYSQL :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2012-05-05'
```

This should work

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2012-05-25'
```

It will work but not used index on "timestamp" column if you have any  because of DATE function. below query used index and give better performance

```sql
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp >= '2012-05-05 00:00:00' 
    AND timestamp <= '2012-05-05 23:59:59'
```

OR

```sql
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE timestamp >= '2012-05-05' AND timestamp < '2012-05-06'
```

Try running these to check stats

```sql
explain SELECT * FROM table
WHERE DATE(timestamp) = '2012-05-25'
```

```sql
explain SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp >= '2012-05-05 00:00:00' 
    AND timestamp <= '2012-05-05 23:59:59'
```

Answer (score 1):

As I was researching this I thought it would be nice to modify the BETWEEN solution to show an example for a particular non-static/string date, but rather a variable date, or today's such as `CURRENT_DATE()`. This **WILL use the index** on the log_timestamp column.

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE
    log_timestamp
    BETWEEN 
        timestamp(CURRENT_DATE()) 
    AND # Adds 23.9999999 HRS of seconds to the current date
        timestamp(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL '86399.999999' SECOND_MICROSECOND));
```

I did the seconds/microseconds to avoid the 12AM case on the next day. However, you could also do `INTERVAL '1 DAY' via comparison operators for a more reader-friendly non-BETWEEN approach:

```
SELECT *
FROM some_table
WHERE
    log_timestamp >= timestamp(CURRENT_DATE()) AND
    log_timestamp < timestamp(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY));
```

Both of these approaches will use the index and should perform MUCH faster. Both seem to be equally as fast.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using SQL parameters to run the query then this would be helpful

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE timestamp between concat(date(?), ' ', '00:00:00') and concat(date(?), ' ', '23:59:59')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(2012-05-05 00:00:00) = '2012-05-05'
```

Answer (score 0):

When I read your question, I thought your were on **Oracle DB** until I saw the tag 'MySQL'. Anyway, for people working with Oracle here is the way:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
where timestamp = to_timestamp('21.08.2017 09:31:57', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me leave here it may help someone
**For people coming from nodejs and expressjs**

```
  getDailyIssueOperations(dateName, date, status) {
    const queryText = `
    select count(*) as total from issues
    where date(${dateName})='${date}' and status='${status}';
    `;
  },
```

in case date and column name are variables please find the implementation usefull