# how to compare timestamp in between 20 to 60 years from a specific timestamp?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a field in the database to store the date of birth of a user in time stamp format, now i want to add a search filter in which only that users are shown whose date of birth between the two min or max limits. for eg. `minimum=20 years` and `maximum=60 years`. How i can compare the time stamp date with these two parameters?
I tried out with `wordpress` `wp_query` like follows:

```
$current = time();
$age_min = strtotime(date('Y')-$_REQUEST['age_min']);
$age_max = strtotime(date('Y')-$_REQUEST['age_max']);

//echo $age_min.'==='.$age_max;
$age = array($age_min,$age_max);
$bars = explode(',',$_REQUEST['bars']);
$radius = $_REQUEST['radius'];
$args = array('orderby' => 'registered',
              'meta_key' => 'active',
              'meta_value' => '1',
              'order' => 'ASC',
              'count_total' => true,
              'meta_query' => array(array('key'     => 'date_of_birth',
                                          'value'   => $age,
                                          'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                                          'type'    => 'DECIMAL',),));
$user_query = new WP_User_Query(array($args,'exclude'=>array($user_id) ));
```

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Many of them aren't ANSI SQL compliant when it comes do date/time.) Column data type?

Comment: what is the database?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483123/comparing-timestamp-dates-in-mysql-with-date-only-parameter

Answer (score 0):

Convert  the `strtotime` back to dates in Min and Max values :

I have converted back to Y-m-d you can convert it to your used `DOB`

```
$age_min = strtotime(date('Y')-$_REQUEST['age_min']);
$age_max = strtotime(date('Y')-$_REQUEST['age_max']);

//echo $age_min.'==='.$age_max;
$age_min = date('Y-m-d', $age_min); 
$age_max = date('Y-m-d', $age_max);
```

And then pass it to arrays :

```
$age = array($age_min,$age_max);
```