# SQL: Convert date to timestamp

Tags: sql, date, timestamp, db2

How can I convert a date to a timestamp?

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM CTP0421
WHERE timestamp <= '2016-04-04'
```

This doesn't work for me.

Comment: you can use `To_char` or `To_date` in appropriate places.. just google these functions ..

Comment: try this where convert(date,timestamp) <= '2016-04-04'

Comment: @pratikgarg Thank you! It work's.

Comment: Tag dbms used. (Neither To_char  nor To_date is ANSI SQL standard functions...)

Comment: Answer of your question is already given on below link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483123/comparing-timestamp-dates-in-mysql-with-date-only-parameter

Comment: @VinodNarwal, it seems like people think this is an Oracle question. (But how could I know, op refuses to let us know...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM CTP0421
WHERE trunc(timestamp) <= to_date('2016-04-04','yyyy-mm-dd');
```

Comment: @jarlh By the comments you can understand that it is ORACLE's dbms, although he answered before it was clear.