# Retrieve records from MYSQL using PHP and by comparing datetime data

Tags: php, mysql

my MYSQL table is as below:

```
id   record_nr    timestamp
1    931          2014-02-15 6:21:00
2    577          2013-05-03 0:19:00
3    323          2012-08-07 11:26:00
```

in PHP I tried to retrieve a record by comparing time as below:

```
$dateTimeString = "2013-07-28 7:23:34";

$query = "SELECT * FROM mytable ";
$query .= "WHERE timestamp <= STR_TO_DATE('".$dateTimeString."', '%H:%i:%s')";
$query .= " ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1";
```

This didn't work. How to retrieve the record #577? Timestamp is not the time the record was created. Rather, it is a date and time associated with that record.

Comment: Since you are comparing only the date portion, you also need to compare the date only portion of the `timestamp` -> `"WHERE DATE(timestamp) <= STR_TO_DATE('".$dateTimeString."', '%H:%i:%s')";` http://stackoverflow.com/a/10483175/689579

Answer (score 0):

Below code can be helpful:

```
$dateTimeString = '2016-12-27 12:59:46';
$query = "SELECT * FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `TIMESTAMP` <= '".$dateTimeString."' 
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Notice the OP has `<=` in their query compared to your `=`? Yours requires an exact match, where they want it to be the next equal **or** lesser. Big difference.

Comment: @sean Thanks for your correction. I have edit my code.

Comment: Sorry, I need to clarify. I don't need an exact match. I just want to pick the record with the closest to $dateTimeString, without going beyond that time.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to

```
$query .= "WHERE timestamp <= '".$dateTimeString."'";
```

It seems to work. Thanks.