# Check the year of timestamps

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have stored timestamps in my database. Timestamps like `483753600`, `799286400`, etc.

I would like to check if the year 2015 would match with any of my timestamps.

The only way that I know that I could do it, would be getting **ALL** the timestamps from the database and then check the year of each timestamp with `getdate(799286400)['year']`. That would be a solution but it's way too bad for the performance! Is there any other softer way to do this?

### Update

This is what I have tried so far:

```php
public function dateOfBirth(string $year): array {
    return $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p.uid')
            ->where("p.dateOfBirth BETWEEN :start AND :end")
            ->setParameter('start', "$year-01-01")
            ->setParameter('end', "$year-01-01")
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

but it returns an empty array.

Comment: Is it easier to just pull the required data instead of checking it after the fact?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483123/how-to-compare-timestamp-dates-with-date-only-parameter-in-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems with your code, first of all you are returning an assignment

```
return $query = $this->createQue...
```

also you set the same parameter value to both `:start` and `:end`, the string `"$year-01-01"` which will not match the stored timestamps, and you don't change the value of `$year` in between so even if it could match it would be an empty range.

You need to determine the starting and ending timestamp for the given year and use them as parameters for the query.

```
public function dateOfBirth(string $year): array {
    // get the DateTimes
    $startDate = new \DateTime("midnight January 1, $year");
    $year += 1;
    $endDate = new \DateTime("midnight January 1, $year");
    // get the timestamps
    $start = $startDate->format('U');
    $end = $endDate->format('U');

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->select('p.uid')
            ->where("p.dateOfBirth > :start")
            ->andWhere("p.dateOfBirth < :end")
            ->setParameter('start', $start)
            ->setParameter('end', $end)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Great answer! That helped me a lot. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are storing epoch timestamps. To check for timestamps that belong to year 2015, an efficient method would be to generate a range of epoch timestamp that represent the year boundaries, and then compare it to the stored values. Assuming that timestamps are stored in column `col`:

```
select exists (
    select 1
    from mytable    
    where col >= unix_timestamp('2015-01-01') and col < unix_timestamp('2016-01-01')
) as exists_year_2015
```

This query will give you a unique record, with a unique column containing a boolean value (`0/1`) that indicates if any record in the table has a timestamp that belongs to year 2015.

Such an expression will be able to take advantage of an index on the timestamp column.

Comment: Thank you but could you please tell me how I could do the same with Symfony? I have updated my question.