# Comparing datetime pattern 'y-M-d H:m:s' select condition with Date type

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I hava a sql query that says:

`SELECT * FROM t_coun_student_sign_1018954616644580  signStu WHERE signStu.is_deleted = 0 AND signStu.student_wid = 1000363408 and signStu.attendance_date >= "2019-12-26 13:00:00.0"`

The column `attendance_date`  is a `date` type and the sql result does not contain `attendance_date = 2019-12-26`. So I thought that `2019-12-26 13:00:00.0` is not converted to `date` type like `2019-12-26`.

But `attendance_date` is also an index and the sql query can use the index.
So if `2019-12-26 00:00:00.0` is not converted to `date` type, how could I make it happen?

What I want to know is that `2019-12-26 00:00:00.0` is to be converted to which type to compare with `attendance_date`, or what does `mysql` do when `date`, `datetime`, `timeStamp` type are compared with `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` pattern string format.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compare timestamp dates with date-only parameter in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10483123/how-to-compare-timestamp-dates-with-date-only-parameter-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what i what know "2019-12-26 00:00:00.0" is convert to which type to compare with attendance_date or what will mysql do when date datetime timeStamp type compare with the 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' pattern string

When operands have different but compatible datatypes in comparing operation then they are converted to the same datatype which guarantees that data loss or change will not occur.

So `DATE` type value is converted to `DATETIME` type in such case, and not backward (converting `'2019-12-26 13:00:00.0'` to `DATE` will alter the value).

To obtain the result which you need (does the literal is a parameter really?) you may convert the literal to `DATA` type explicitly:

```
and signStu.attendance_date >= DATE('2019-12-26 13:00:00.0')
```

Comment: how can you know it convert to `DATETIME ` type,not timestamp as Tim Biegeleisen 
 writed @Tim Biegeleisen

Comment: You might as well just write `WHERE ... AND attendance_date > '2019-12-26'` here.

Comment: @qijun Both field and literal does not contain timezone info. So DATETIME is the closest datatype compatible to both field and literal. Moreover, DATETIME is more wide, a lot of values of this datatype cannot be converted to TIMESTAMP at all. Of course, it is possible that inner server code performs datetime types compare in TIMESTAMP - but I have not seen such information in the documentation.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think that the literal shown is a parameter really (and I have asked about this in my answer).

Comment: @Akina Yes; there is nothing _wrong_ with what you did, but I don't believe it to be necessary on MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I know the part of the task only - not more than OP says. I see he uses a literal which contains time part, and he has a problem while compare because of time part presence. There is a lot of variants to solve. We eject any operations with the field (index usage loss) - so we may operate with literal only. We may alter this literal before the query execution, or we may truncate it during execution. I select the last option as it is more general - I don't know where and how this literal is formed. And I see nothing wrong - the expression is evaluated once before query execution.

Answer (score 0):

If `attendance_date` be a date only column, then in the context of comparing it against a timestamp literal, it will behave as a timestamp on *midnight* of that date.  So, assuming there were a record which had an attendance date value of `2019-12-27`, then the `WHERE` clause would become:

```
WHERE ... AND '2019-12-27 00:00:00' > '2019-12-26 13:00:00.0'
               ^^^ the attendance "date"
```

Depending on the logic you want, you may have to change the `WHERE` clause to use some derivative of the attendance date.

Comment: ok，so it convet to timestamp time,but some one tell me Implicit type conversion will not use index,because the `attendance_date` is date type, but this sql can use the index of  `attendance_date`

Comment: So long as `attendance_date` be _not_ wrapped in a function call of any sort, that column would at least be a _candidate_ for using an index.  As to whether or not MySQL would actually use any index, well that would depend on your data and explain plan.

Comment: you said it will behave as a timestamp，is that means the attendance_date  convert to timestamp  and not datetime type

Comment: I don't know the implementation details.  What I am saying is that it is perfectly legal to compare a date against a timestamp literal.  As my answer says, in this case the date would behave as a timestamp on the same date, with the time portion set to midnight.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Date" function with column then you are able to compare.

Like- Date(signStu.attendance_date)

Comment: *Use ... function with column then you are able to compare.* This prevents index usage and degrades the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql DATE_FORMAT` function for the query like below
DATE_FORMAT(signStu.attendance_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H.%i.%s') >= DATE_FORMAT("2019-12-26 13:00:00.0",  '%Y-%m-%d %H.%i.%s')